# Spring Boot ApplicationContextRunner doesn't configure logback?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I"m using spring boot 2.7.13 on java 11. I'm trying to use `ApplicationContextRunner` for some integration testing, with most configuration set by the runner's `propertyValues()` method. For logging, I would like to use logback and take advantage of [configuring logging through properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.13/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.logging). But I find that ApplicationContextRunner doesn't configure logback. Instead, it seems slf4j is configuring logback to a default--log everything at DEBUG--and then nothing else changes it.

I ended up with this sample program:

```
package org.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.runner.ApplicationContextRunner;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ApplicationContextRunner()
                .withPropertyValues("logging.level.root=info",
                        "logging.level.org.example=trace")
                .run(ctx -> {
                    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);
                    logger.trace("Trace message");
                    logger.debug("Debug message");
                    logger.info("Info message");
                });
    }
}
```

and POM:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.13</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>scratch</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>scratch</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run this the entire output is:

```
09:10:22.108 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6c3f5566
09:10:22.123 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
09:10:22.157 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
09:10:22.162 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
09:10:22.165 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
09:10:22.168 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
09:10:22.260 [main] DEBUG org.example.Runner - Debug message
09:10:22.260 [main] INFO org.example.Runner - Info message
09:10:22.264 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6c3f5566, started on Fri Jun 30 09:10:22 EDT 2023
```

I did some troubleshooting. It looks like spring boot's main mechanism to configure logging is in `LoggingApplicationListener`, which configures logging when it receives certain ApplicationEvents. But as far as I can tell, when the context is started by ApplicationContextRunner, no LoggingApplicationListener is created. Even when I inject a LoggingApplicationListener into the context, it doesn't receive the necessary events to setup logging.

I'm a little surprised by all of this. The documentation doesn't have any caveats about configuring logging through properties. Logback is a popular logging framework, and ApplicationContextRunner is popular for testing. But not only does the configuration not happen, but starting the context logs a bunch of unnecessary messages about spring internals. I feel like I must be doing something wrong here, because otherwise people would be complaining about this behavior.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a straightforward way to configure logging through properties when using ApplicationContextRunner?

Answer (score -1):

i recommend to you configure logging in propertie file and not programmatically.

example:

src/main/resources/application.yml  // application.properties

```
logging:
  file:
    max-size: 100MB
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.example: TRACE
server:
 port: 8080
...
```

Thats is the default way to configure logging :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: Did you try this? I tried adding an `application.properties` file with the same logging values, but it didn't make any difference. AFAIK setting configuration through `propertyValues()` is supposed to be the way to configure an application context runner.